# Как сгенерировать все возможные размещения чисел из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть список чисел `s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Нужно составить двумерный массив `m[7**7][7]`, содержащий в строках все возможные варианты размещений из `s`.
Реализовал вариант с `random`, но он очень медленный..

```
dx = 7
dy = 7 ** 7
m = [[1 for x in range(dx)] for y in range(dy)]
i = 0
k = 0
while i < dy:
    for j in range(dx):
        m[i][j] = random.randint(1, 7)
    for d in range(i):
        if d != i and m[i] == m[d]:
            i -= 1
            k += 1
    i += 1
```

Так же уточнение: возможны перестановки и повторы чисел в любое место. Т.е. вариант `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`тоже верный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

res = list(itertools.product(s, repeat=len(s)))

print(len(res))   # 823543
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать с использованием `itertools`

```
import itertools
s = [1, 2, 3]
items = list(itertools.permutations(s))
>>> items
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

В результате получим массив кортежей, каждый из которых содержит один из вариантов расстановки.

Comment: Спасибо. Но я совсем забыл уточнить важный момент: возможны перестановки и повторы чисел в любое место. Т.е. вариант [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]тоже верный.

Comment: @Андрей, тогда у вас будет 1716 комбинаций: `list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(s, len(s)))`

Comment: @MaxU, для семи чисел должно быть 823543 уникальных комбинаций. Спасибо.